# PHP: Which functions and techniques a good programmer should not use?

Tags: php

Which functions and techniques should a good programmer not use?

Probably `ereg` is one of them.

Is it a good practice to use the `global` keyword, or should I avoid it as much as possible?

Comment: Functions and techniques are completely different. For functions, it's as simple as "Is it deprecated? Don't use it.". To learn good technique, you should read a book or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Alin But theres also a few others you should look at. Most of these are basic knowledge as you progress in your programming and it is your responsibility to keep up with the latest language evolution and best practices.

Of the top of my head I can give you a few though :

```
eval() 
goto()
```

Suppressing errors with @ for example `@copy() or @mkdir`

Just to name a few. The internet is full of good articles on this topic.

http://www.kavoir.com/2008/12/bad-practices-in-php-coding.html

Theres a whole lot of good reads so happy googling.

Comment: `goto` isn't a function, and shouldn't be followed by `()`.

Comment: yeah i know I was talking in a bit more general theoretical way.

Answer (score 7):

Good programmer should understand how things are working and decide when and how it's best to use them. Mostly everything has good use for it and everything can be used in wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use short open tags. Short open tags look like this `<? //somecode ?>`. There are several problems with those.

One of them is that on some servers short open tags might be turned off in the config which would draw your PHP code useless.

Another problem might be that it can cause conflicts with the XML opening tag.

Comment: I've heard this one before, it always seemed ridiculous. If your server is misconfigured it can screw things up regardless of the tag type you use, and if your server is pushing XML pages through the PHP interpreter you've messed up badly somewhere

Comment: None the less you have to plan for mis-configured servers when you build stuff which you plan to release. The comment that you have to fix your server is void as you often have no way to configure the server...

Comment: But anyway, who seriously works on PHP files with an XML editor, or pipes it through xmllint?

Comment: I've never heard a convincing argument against short tags.

Answer (score 0):

*A good programmer should not use deprecated functions and techniques.*

Comment: Hmm. Or you could ask him to improve the question. Vague answers are almost as bad as vague questions on SO ;-)